# Bootstrap table on hover disable for selected row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap for the on-hover effect for my table rows. But I want to remove the on-hover effect when a table row is selected. I set a class (select-row) using JavaScript when a row is selected. Does not seem to be working for me.  I'm using the not clause in the css.

My css:

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr:not(.select-row):hover > td, 
.table-hover > tbody > tr:not(.select-row):hover > th {
    background-color: #f5fafe;
    color: black;
}

tr.select-row {
    background-color: #bddef9;
}
```

Html:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
   <tr>
       <td>xxx</td>
       <td>xxx</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order for the selected row background not to change, you need to specifically overwrite the existing hover style.

Bootstrap targets the `td` background on hover rather than `tr`.

This works:

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr.select-row:hover > td,
.select-row > td {
    background-color: #bddef9;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ryga2nj/1/)

Comment: This worked for me with Bootstrap 3.3 and Angular 1.5. I was using a ng-class="{selected: selectedTable == tbl}" attribute in my ng-repeat row to highlight, and the hover was overriding the selection. After changing select-row to selected Jack's fix solved my problem.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 targets the `tr` itself, not the `td` inside it.

Answer (score 2):

In **Bootstrap v5** you have to set `box-shadow: none` on the `<td>` element to override the hover behavior.

It took me a long time to figure out why there is no `background-color` rule for the `:hover` pseudo-class. They applied a kind-of-infinite inset box shadow to mimic a change in background color, without overriding it actually.

Comment: This is hacker style. 100% works.

Answer (score 1):

[Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1585362/jack)'s solution does not work for me (Chromium 62.0.3202.94). What I found working is something that uses the CSS `:not()` selector. So you give the class `tableRowHover` as class for the table to enable a fancy mouse-over effect. It's defined in the CSS file as

```
.tableRowHover tbody tr:not(.tableRowHoverOff):hover td { .... }
```

and then you can use the class `tableRowHoverOff` for every `<tr>` where you want to explicitly disable it.

Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mk319zzm/

Answer (score -3):

jquery solution to this problem

```
$('tr').select(function()
{    
 $(this).removeClass('classtoremove'); 
});
```

you can now apply .css method to $(this) object

Comment: The OP is not asking about `text selection`, so the jquery `select` method would not apply here. Also, there is no class to be removed.