# Bootstrap hover table: disable hover efect on specific row

Tags: css, hover, bootstrap-5

Found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441839/bootstrap-table-on-hover-disable-for-selected-row/28442445) but it doesn't contain the answer to my one as it suggests to set fixed background on the specific row which can ruin the style for example in case `bg-gradient` is set on the parent.

Either `tr.exclude:hover > td {background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);}` or `tr.exclude:hover {background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);}` look like just add another background color over the hover's one instead of replace it as the new color appears in case alpha is not `0` but the hover effect is still here if alpha is `0`.

Bootstrap's [Table](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/content/tables/) documentation says that "*`.table-hover` enables a hover state on table rows within a `<tbody>`*".

But in fact it applies the hover state even for the `<tr>`s outside the `<tbody>`.

Is there a working way which would just disable the hover effect on the specific row of the Bootstrap hover table?

Comment: I think it would help us if you could include a small working example - the solution may depend on exactly what the hover effect on the other rows is to be or what the other permanent settings are like background on parent which you mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your `{background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);}` with `{box-shadow: none;}`.

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple, assign one class to all rows except that specific row on which you don't want the effect to take place.
In table:hover statement use select child class.

HTML:-

---

```
<table id="tbl">
  <tr class="enabled-Hover">
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="enabled-Hover">
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="disabled-Hover">
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="enabled-Hover">
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:-

```
#tbl *, #tbl{
  border:1px solid #000;
}

#tbl:hover .enabled-Hover{
  background-color:#f55;
}
```

Comment: This method replaces the background, just like in my example. I need to completely disable the hover effect.